# Should I use \qty or \SI for siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

Which command would be the correct way to display a unit? To be frank, I do not see any difference between `\qty` and `\SI`.

Comment: It might depend on whether you're planning on sending the code to someone else who might be using the old siunitx, for example an overleaf user

Comment: @daleif https://www.texdev.net/2021/06/30/siunitx-v2-to-v3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\SI` is the old version of the command from `siunitx` v2, and it was kept in `siunitx` v3 solely for backwards compatibility, so for new documents you should definitely use `\qty`.  The same goes for `\si`→`\unit`, `\SIlist`→`\qtylist` and `\SIrange`→`\qtyrange`, plus a few other commands (see section [5–Upgrading from version 2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#section.0.5) of the manual and [this blog post](https://www.texdev.net/2021/06/30/siunitx-v2-to-v3) on TeXdev.net).  One of the reasons that `\SI` was replaced is that its name was a bit awkward: you're not going to typeset an SI, but a quantity or an unit, so the new names are much more meaningful.

There should be in fact little to no difference in the output from either commands, because the purpose of the package is, after all, still the same, although internals were greatly changed from v2, as well some option interfaces and font management (where most of the differences, if any, seem to be expected), so if you want to update from v2 to v3, take a look at the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) documentation.