# TeXstudio autocompletion for \SI command (siuntix)

Tags: texstudio, siunitx

I use TeXstudio, and almost all commands I use on a regular basis autocomplete, which is very helpful... except for the `\SI{}{}` command from the `siunitx` package. I use this command constantly, and I always have to actually type out both sets of brackets. This is different from the fraction command where typing `\fra` and pressing tab gets you `\frac{num}{denom}`. Is there any way to get `\SI` to autocomplete?

Note: the units themselves (e.g., `\meter`) DO autocomplete correctly.

Comment: Maybe TeXstudio adopted to the changes to `siunitx` and removed `\SI` from the autocompletion list. [You ought to use `\qty` instead.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603217)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you for the suggestion. The reason I haven't been using \qty is that it squishes the unit right up against the number, unlike \SI which leaves (what looks like a) comma-length space. Maybe there's a way to fix this issue, in which case I'd be happy to switch to \qty.

Comment: `\qty` should produce the same output as `\SI`. Either something is broken or you've got maybe a very old version of `siunitx`. We will have to see a minimal example to see what's going on. Maybe the default for `\qty` is different.

Comment: I use both TexStudio and the new version of `siunitx` to typeset `\qty`. I don't see any difference in typesetting and spacing between `\qty` and `\SI`. But then again: I am using LuaLaTeX to compile. Tthe manual states on page 59 in *paragraph 9.1*  some remarks on **font encoding** especially concerning PDFLaTeX font handling. Could that give you a clou about the different spacing you encounter?