# three column nomenclature coding for the below image

Tags: tables, nomenclature, nomencl

[image]

creating three column nomenclature is hard, help me out

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}



\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}


\end{document}

Comment: @JEEVAN Your minimal code put in a comment not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is really not a page to let others do your work, I'll help you out. I'm sure you can complete the table yourself. You can also have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112884/237192) if you dislike my approach.

I'd simply use a standard `tabular` for this, together with the `booktabs` package for good-looking tables and the `siunitx` package for correct typesetting of SI units.

Note that if a subscript is *not* a mathematical object (index, counter, ...), but has a "normal language meaning" (like "o" for "oxygen", "max" for "maximum", ...) you should set it upright (`a_\mathrm{b}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{Nomenclature.}
        \label{tab:my_label}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description}                       & \textbf{Unit}                    \\ \midrule
            $D$             & Diffusion coefficient in the Biofilm phase & \unit{\meter\squared\per\second} \\
            $D_o$           & Diffusion coefficient in the Gas phase     & \unit{\meter\squared\per\second} \\ 
            \ldots          & \ldots                                     & \ldots                           \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

### Edit

Apparently in newer versions of `siunitx` one is supposed to use `\unit` instead of `\si` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603251/237192)), so I changed the code accordingly.